# Using Puppet to install a specific kernel

Tags: centos, kernel, puppet

I'm using Puppet to install a specific kernel on an agent. The problem is, I can't quite seem to give it a version. I have the following:

```
class kernel::install_kernel_version {
  # Make sure the 'kernel' package is installed in build agent
  case $::osfamily {
    'RedHat': {
      require epel
      package {'kernel':
        ensure => '2.6.32-431.29.2.e16.x86_64'}
      }
    default: {
      fail("Module is not compatible with ${::operatingsystem}")
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I to run it, there's no effect. Presumably because it doesn't know the kernel version exists.

Comment: can you provide output of `--verbose` and `--debug`? How are you applying the class? is the kernel listed in the output of `rpm -qa |grep kernel`?

Comment: +1 to Petey, "no effect" usually means that the resource is already in sync. Also, make sure you `include` the class!

Comment: @FelixFrank is right about that. Make sure you include the `class` some way. either `hiera_include`, the `puppet dashboard` or a `node definition` somewhere.